# how to bind the Height property to a variable in c# code wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, path, height

I am trying to bind a Height property of a rectangle depending on a variable in a c# code .I Wrote this code in the XML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="H1" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding Path=H1 }"  Margin="29,83,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149"/>
```

and in the c# code in the window load event :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int H1 = 50;
}
```

but there is no action and the height is 0,and the intelicense says to me that "H1" is never used 
,Where is the  problem ?

Comment: You have a lot of issues in you code. You should investigate [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use following code to set height.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.H1.DataContext = new { H1 = 50 }; // here this.H1, refers to <Rectangle x:Name="H" .. 
}
```